# add tabs (spaces) to strings in plots for Octave / Matlab

Tags: matlab, gnuplot, octave

How can I add tabs (spaces) to strings for plots in Octave see code below. It doesn't create a **tab** (There should be a tab between Signal and Max Freq in the plot)

Also it produces warning messages

warning: text_renderer: skipping missing glyph for character '9'
warning: called from
    annotation>update_textbox at line 1080 column 11
    annotation at line 248 column 7

```
clf
plot(0:0)
var=456
t1='Signal ';
t2=[char(9), 'Max Freq'];
t3=[char(10), 'nextline',num2str(var)];
str=strcat(t1,t2,t3);
annotation('textbox',...
[0.15 0.65 0.3 0.15],...
'String',{str},...
'FontSize',14,...
'FontName','Arial',...
'LineStyle','--',...
'EdgeColor',[1 1 0],...
'LineWidth',2,...
'BackgroundColor',[0.9  0.9 0.9],...
'Color',[0.84 0.16 0]);
```

[image: Plot]

Ps:  I'm using Octave 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 64bit

Comment: Does `tabstr = sprintf('\t')` work?

Comment: @jodag unfortunately no that doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you create a separate textbox for each tab stop? Seems to me the easiest way to line up text.

Comment: From a few experiments I just ran it looks like tabs are ignored in MATLAB textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I added t4 for blanks...doesn't look very nice. Also note I am using Matlab, not Octave so I didn't get your error. Not sure about that.

```
clf
plot(0:0)
var=456
t1='Signal ';
t4 = blanks(5);
t2=[char(9),t4, 'Max Freq'];
t3=[char(10), 'nextline',num2str(var)];
str=strcat(t1,t2,t3);
annotation('textbox',...
[0.15 0.65 0.3 0.15],...
'String',{str},...
'FontSize',14,...
'FontName','Arial',...
'LineStyle','--',...
'EdgeColor',[1 1 0],...
'LineWidth',2,...
'BackgroundColor',[0.9  0.9 0.9],...
'Color',[0.84 0.16 0]);
```

[image: The plot fixed]